# Plotly subplots, hide x axis labels

Tags: python, plotly

[image: My plot here]

How to remove x axis label from my subplots , i want them only on legend

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=4,)
for i,j in enumerate(to_show_up):
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y =df[j] ,name = j ),row=1, col=i+1)
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
for i,j in enumerate(to_show_down):
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y =df[j] ,name = j ),row=2, col=i+1)
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1200, title_text="Метрики сотовой связи")


fig.show()
```

Comment: You should add some code to your question

Answer (score 8):

From the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#toggling-axis-labels):

> **Toggling axis labels:** The axis tick mark labels can be disabled by
> setting the `showticklabels` axis property to `False`.
>
> Here is an example of disabling tick labels in all subplots for a
> faceted figure created using Plotly Express:

```py
import plotly.express as px 

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col="species") 

fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False) # Hide x axis ticks 
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False) # Hide y axis ticks

fig.show()
```

Comment: it doesn work (( updated my question with code.

Comment: I see you set the yaxes ticks to False, have you tried the xaxes ? since you want to remove the tick on x axes right? not the y axis

Comment: thx a lot ) just dummy mistake

Comment: glad that help. Don't forget to accept my answer as solution :)